# Mobile scroll offscreen

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm making a mobile site and have a scrollable bar, but for some reason instead of scrolling down the side-bar it just scrolls down the whole website (which for some random reason is just white and seems to just add to the total height of the website)

So the question is how do I make it so that mobile users cannot move their viewport?

So for example:

[image]

the mobile user can ONLY view the blue part of this image?

Thanks and sorry for the bad wording of this question.

Comment: Please some the relevant `HTML` and `CSS` along with your question Lewis

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found the answer in the viewport meta.

Using the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

makes it so that the user cannot scale or move the viewport... as the tag implies :)