# Mobile scroll when object offscreen without loosing text-size.adjust capability

Tags: html, css

So I had the problem on mobile described in the following question: [Mobile scroll offscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617601/mobile-scroll-offscreen)  :
When an object would go offscreen, it seems to increase the total width/height of the website, so the object stays on the screen. I implemented an animation where an css objects leaves the screen and then reenters from the other side.

Following the answer to the mentioned question, I added `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">` to my HTML file.
That problem is solved, but now it will ignore the ccs code

```
text-size.adjust: auto;
text-size-adjust: 60%;
```

, so my layout is now messed up on mobile (before adding the HTML it worked perfectly fine).

Is there any way to prevent the offscreen behavior without blocking the text-size.adjust ability? Hiding the part that is offscreen would help to.

I use Google Chrome (Version 94.0.4606.85) on an Android (Version T810XXU2DRH1/T310DBT2DRH2) Tablet (Samsumb Tab S2 SM-T810)

I'm happy about every helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the viewpoint deeper on [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) I found out that `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` will set the width of the viewpoint to the device width (so no offscreen viewpoint, I assume that's possible with height too, but I didn't try) and set the zoom level to 100% when the website is loaded.